# .htaccess: how to redirect non-www to www except for subdomains

Tags: .htaccess

I've used the following code to redirect `example.com` to `www.example.com`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

However, I have `www.example.com` set up in Wordpress multisite with subdomains, so I need the above rule to only work for `example.com`, and not for `site-x.example.com`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will apply to `example.com` and only **`example.com`**.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

1. Check if HTTP_HOST starts with *example.com* and ends here. Stop if false, continue if true.
2. Redirect to URL with leading *www*.

Comment: Without an ending `$` matches like `example.com.example.com` are possible.

Answer (score 2):

Some options:

The rather generic:

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^\w+\.\w+$`

A blacklist:

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www|site-x)\. [NC]`

Or a whitelist:

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(example1|example2)\.(com|net|co)$ [NC]`